# Portlet repository

Tags: portlet

I'm looking for portlets to embed into a portal web site ([Liferay](http://www.liferay.com)).

As portlets are standardized (JSR-168 or JSR-286), I was looking for portlet solutions over the web, but didn't get a lot of results. For the moment, I'm looking for a kind of news manager portlet.
Here are a few portlets I found :

- https://wiki.jasig.org/display/PLT/Announcements+Portlet+Administration+Guide
- https://sourcesup.cru.fr/newsportlet/

But I'm also looking for other portlets, a portlets repository will be perfect!
Here the ones I know :

- https://wiki.jasig.org/display/PLT/Home
- http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/community-plugins
- http://www.jboss.org/portletswap/portlet_catalog.html

So if you have any link or information to share?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also check this :

[myoffice24X7](http://www.myoffice24x7.com/)

This is has lot of portlets, but they are paid, you can still try the trial versions.